# Call an event when the active spreadsheet changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working with a spreadsheet that has multiple sheets, I would like my custom toolbar menu to change dynamically depending on which sheet is open at the time.

Is there an event that can be called when the active spreadsheet is changed? Or some other method of updating the menus as I change between sheets.

Answer (score 2):

With this little code it is possible to create a dynamic menu, based on the active sheet.

### Code

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function onOpen() {
  ss.addMenu("Extra", 
    [{name: "Sheet A", functionName: "A"},
     {name: "Sheet B", functionName: "B"}, 
     {name: "Sheet C", functionName: "C"}
    ]);
}

function onEdit() {
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet().getName(), nMenu;
  ss.removeMenu("Extra");    

  switch (activeSheet) { 
    case "A":
      nMenu = [{name: "Sheet B", functionName: "B"}, 
        {name: "Sheet C", functionName: "C"}];
      break;
    case "B":
      nMenu = [{name: "Sheet A", functionName: "A"}, 
        {name: "Sheet C", functionName: "C"}];
      break;
    case "C":
      nMenu = [{name: "Sheet A", functionName: "A"},
        {name: "Sheet B", functionName: "B"}];
      break;
  }      
  ss.addMenu("Extra", nMenu);
}
```

### Example

I've created an example file for you: [Dynamic Menu](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdF9nUVg0WEN3d2o4X2lldHpXM24yREE&usp=sharing)

### Remark

The menu is *only* changed when any of the cells in the active sheet is edited.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at the onEdit function, so if I understand correctly there is no other way to do this without first editing a cell to call the event?

Comment: @T27M It is not possible to have an event handler on the `selectTab`.